# Configure a WinHTTP application to use Fiddler

Tags: asp-classic, fiddler

I need to see the actual requests being made from a asp page to the webservice(which calls another webservice). All these requests happen on the same local box. I ran the "proxycfg -p http=127.0.0.1:8888;https=127.0.0.1:8888" on the command prompt based on

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-WinHTTP: How can I configure a WinHTTP application to use Fiddler?

I now see the webservice wsdl requests in Fiddler but not the actual requests. Would someone know why??

Comment: Please elaborate on what technologies you're using exactly? How is your code issuing the web service request?

Answer (score -1):

If your WS calls are going to your local machine, make sure the URLs they are using are "localhost." instead of "localhost" - notice the dot in the first instance. Otherwise fiddler never gets a chance to pick up the request.